# Next.js 12 and remove .babelrc, now I get an error with Typescript/Jsx

Tags: typescript, next.js, babeljs

So, with Next.js 12, you can remove the .bablerc file and use their builtin update that builds faster. I have NOT noticed any improvement in build time, the opposite actually.

But, because I removed my .babelrc file, I am now getting these errors that spring from my usage of Typescript.

```
Error: error: Unexpected token `BreakdownItem`. Expected jsx identifier
const breakdown = <BreakdownItem>get(cart, 'breakdown', {});
                | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Another:

```
return <ConfigReturn>{treatment, treatmentConfig, isLoaded, isError};
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How to solve this without a .babelrc file?

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I'm coming up on the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed to resolve itself in version 12.0.7 (maybe 12.0.4). Have you tried those versions? Also, don't forget to remove ur babelrc file. (I renamed mine).